# Paraview IntegrateVariables and Plot Selection Over Time

Tags: paraview

I am using the IntegrateVariables filter in Paraview to integrate an energy density rho over a cylindrical volume (obtained using the Clip filter). I need to plot this integrated rho over time, which should be possible using 'Plot Selection Over Time'. However, I can't find a way of applying the filter to the right variable and when I press Apply, Paraview just buffers until I force quit. Can anyone help?

Comment: can you share your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to specify to a PlotXXX filter which array to process.
But there is the 'PassArray' filter which allows to extract the arrays you want, limiting the computation and the memory consumption.